# История - Первое ЭВМ на базе мейнфрейма

Tags: железо

Первое ЭВМ на базе мейнфрейма было построено на лампах или на полупроводниках?
Знаю, что первые ПК были на лампах, а вот мейнфреймы...

Comment: Что-то я не уверен, что история вычислительной техники у нас онтопик.

Comment: > Знаю, что первые ПК были на лампах

может наоборот?

Comment: История не в топе, но почему бы не ответить?)

Comment: @Escaper, ЭВМ - она, а не оно :Р

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Историю мэйнфреймов принято считать от [IBM System/360](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_System/360). Это ЭВМ [третьего поколения](http://gym075.edusite.ru/istoriyavt.html#III_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5), а там, как известно уже использовались интегральные схемы.